# Best way to calculate when div hits bottom?

Tags: jquery, dom, html, offset

I have an application that generates div boxes dynamically. The boxes are overlapping each other, and moved 15px down and to the right.

However, when the bottom of a box hits the bottom of the page I want the next box to turn up on the top on the page. The same goes for when the right side of a box hits the right side of the page (ie. the boxes shouldn't be able to go outside the page).

Below is my code, but it doesn't work as I want. The boxes gets "out of bounds" on the right side before turning up on the left side, and regarding the bottom it's not really right either. I guess there is a better way to accomplish this, I just don't know what it is.

```
var win = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'window',
    'width': this.width,
    'height': this.height
}).appendTo('#container');

var containerHeight = $('#container').height();
var maxBottom = (desktopHeight / 2);

var containerWidth = $('#container').width();
var maxRight = desktopWidth;

var prev = win.prev('.window');
if (prev.length > 0) {

   win.offset({ 
    left: prev.offset().left + 15, 
    top: prev.offset().top + 15 });

    if (prev.offset().top >= maxBottom){
        win.offset({
            top: 10
        });
    }
    if (prev.offset().left >= maxRight){
        win.offset({
            left: 0
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the element's `.offset().top` property plus the element's `.height()` are equal or greater than the `.height()` if the document:

```
var myBox   = $('#my-box'),
    bHeight = myBox.height(),
    wHeight = $(window).height(),
    bWidth  = myBox.width(),
    wWidth  = $(window).width();

if (myBox.offset().top + bHeight >= wHeight) {
    myBox.css({
        top : 0
    });
}

if (myBox.offset().left + bWidth >= wWidth) {
    myBox.css({
        left : 0
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! However, '$' should be removed before myBox.offset(). :)